# Returning all records until a record equals a certain value Access / SQL query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

I am trying to set up a query that will return all of the records for a group in a table until a record value in that table equals a certain value.

I am currently selecting the top 2 records for each group in the table with a sub query however that doesn't work out if the event I need to record falls outside of the top 2. I thought about increasing the sub query to a top 3 however then that returns to much data if the event in question occurs in the top 2.

For example if I have

```
Name Date Event
Tom  5/5  Test
Tom  5/5  Test
Tom  5/5  Stop Test
Tom  5/5  Test
Tom  5/5  Test
Gary 5/5  Test
Gary 5/5  Stop Test
Gary 5/5  Test
```

I would need to return  the first 3 records for Tom and the first 2 records for gary. Is there an easy way to do this within Access / SQL?

Comment: where is your query ? can we see it...

Comment: You said...  "until a record value in that table equals a certain value"...what is the values for Tom's record?

Comment: Is this question about MS SQL Server or MS Access? They are different databases.

Comment: I could use either one I would need a method to do it in either sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: The value would be I would need all records up to and including the first "stop test" event

Comment: You seem to be thinking about an order of rows here but a table is an unordered set. And in your sample data there is nothing to use as a sort order. You need to provide more details here so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SqlFiddle doesn't seem to be working for MSSQL at the moment.

Here's something that should get you on the right path.  I'm assuming that the date in your example also implies a time and therefore an ordering of events.  Given that, the SQL below will generate a row number based on the datetime and "grouped" by the name.  The query against the PartialResult CTE will return the rows where the generated row number are <= the first occurrence of the "Stop Test" event for each name.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

CREATE TABLE [NameDateEvent]
(
  [Name] [NVARCHAR](100) NOT NULL,
  [Date] DATETIME NOT NULL,
  [Event] [NVARCHAR](100) NOT NULL,
)
GO
INSERT INTO [NameDateEvent]
    VALUES 
        ('Tom','2016-02-26 14:55:38.517', 'Test')
        ,('Tom','2016-02-26 14:55:39.517', 'Test')
        ,('Tom','2016-02-26 14:55:40.517', 'Stop Test')
        ,('Tom','2016-02-26 14:55:41.517', 'Test')
        ,('Tom','2016-02-26 14:55:42.517', 'Test')
        ,('Gary','2016-02-26 14:55:43.517', 'Test')
        ,('Gary','2016-02-26 14:55:44.517', 'Stop Test')
        ,('Gary','2016-02-26 14:55:45.517', 'Test')
GO

;WITH PartialResult AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [Date]) AS [RowNumByName]
    FROM [NameDateEvent]
)
SELECT *
FROM PartialResult pr
WHERE pr.[RowNumByName] <= (SELECT MIN([RowNumByName]) FROM PartialResult prr WHERE prr.Name = pr.Name AND prr.Event = 'Stop Test')

ROLLBACK
```

Comment: I have used what you provided however It is only returning the information for Tom and not Gary any thoughts?

Comment: When I ran the sample I provided, I got results for both so I'd assume it's somehow data related.  Is there anything fundamentally different about the table structure I created and what you're actually using?  Is my assumption about the date (that it includes a time component and that the rows are unique)?  Any way you can share more specifics about the data, maybe a pastebin of some examples?

Comment: Your assumption about the date time was correct.  The only thing different is that I already have an auto number id field which I would think would take the place of the RowNumByName Field but that is most likely where I am incorrect.

Comment: My guess then is that the auto number field you're using is incremententing sequentially, regardless of whether it's Tom or Gary whereas the "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY...)" in my example is going to be specific to each name.

Comment: I modified my example locally with an equivalent of the autoincrement and I get good results regardless of whether I use it or the RowNumByName so that's not the explanation, at least given the way my data is structured.